# traffic tunneling using C# [ transparent reflecting]

Tags: c#, proxy, tunneling

see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTYEF.png) or [here](http://ckhost.ir/images/92507656218417369092.png)!

as u see in picture the EsetNOD antivirus (ekren.exe) transparently redirect the IDM traffic to port 30606 that ekren.exe is listening to it and forward it to remote host.

[IDM.exe:{Local-30606}] <==>[{Local-30606}:ekren.exe:{Remote-XX}] <==>[{listen-XX}:R-App]

**First** ,how EsetNOD redirect the IDM traffic to that port,is there any trick or it should be system hooks or ring0 privilege?

The ProxyFire Do the same thing you can redirect an all of application traffic through proxy.is there any way to deal with all network (include application and services) traffic ,something like using an app as a gateway?

**Second** ,how to deal with any request (https,dns,ssh,p2p,etc),is it possible to detect one app.exe requests and send some of them directly and some through tunnel?

**Third** ,any help for encrypt/compress the traffic between TClinet & TServer And reflecting the LocalApp (Request/Response) to/from Remote Machine.

sorry for asking many questions and thanks alot :x